# Populate a QTextDocument from a .odt file

Tags: c++, rich-text-editor, opendocument, qtextdocument

I am writing a rich text editor using C++ and Qt.
For now, I would like it to support (at least) the .odt format.

I found QTextDocumentWriter for writing the contents of the QTextDocument to a file, but I can't seem to find anything to read that back into the QTextDocument, which obviously makes saving it sort of useless in the first place.

So the question is, how do I load an .odt document into a QTextDocument?

Comment: I don't think there's something predefined for that in the Qt framework (as far as I know, at least). But this may be of interest (untested): http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/OpenDocument+format+Reader%2BWriter+odt?content=80650

Comment: http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-8837

Answer (score 1):

Qt does not currently support the ODT format. [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) has code that does parses ODT to a QTextDocument. Beware: Okular source code is released under GPL license.